Hero background slider section in React
I am currently in the process of developing the hero section of my website, and I have implemented a slider effect that is designed to showcase a captivating background image along with a variety of text elements on each individual slider. The slider is functioning flawlessly, transitioning smoothly between different slides without any technical issues. However, I am facing a problem where the background images are not displaying as expected, which detracts from the overall visual appeal of the hero section. I would greatly appreciate your assistance in troubleshooting this issue to ensure that the background images appear correctly. This component is intended to serve as the Hero component for my website, and it plays a crucial role in making a strong first impression on visitors. Thank you very much for your help!


import React from "react";
import Slider from "react-slick";
import "slick-carousel/slick/slick.css";
import "slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css";
import "./Hero.css";

const Hero = () => {
  const sliderSettings = {
    dots: true,
    infinite: true,
    speed: 500,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 4000,
    fade: false,
  };

  const slides = [
    {
      backgroundImage:
        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/718aT6EGL4L.__AC_SX300_SY300_QL70_FMwebp_.jpg",
      title: "Welcome to Our Store",
      description: "Find the best deals on the latest products.",
    },
    {
      backgroundImage:
        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/41pTMpnKFhL._AC_UF480,480_SR480,480_.jpg",
      title: "Exclusive Offers",
      description: "Enjoy special discounts and offers only for you.",
    },
    {
      backgroundImage:
        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81y296p3rdL._AC_UL480_FMwebp_QL65_.jpg",
      title: "New Arrivals",
      description: "Check out the latest additions to our collection.",
    },
  ];

  return (
    <Slider {...sliderSettings} className="hero-slider">
      {slides.map((slide, index) => (
        <div
          key={index}
          className="hero-slide"
          style={{
            backgroundImage: `url(${slide.backgroundImage})`,
            blockSize: "100vh",
            backgroundSize: "cover",
            backgroundPosition: "center",
          }}
        >
          <div className="slide-content">
            <h1>{slide.title}</h1>
            <p>{slide.description}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </Slider>
  );
};

export default Hero;


Please provide supporting screenshots of what the background looks like, and what you intend for it to look like.

Please check your CSS in the inspect element i am providing some code for you to help check the issue.

.hero-slider {
  position: relative;
}

.hero-slide {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh; 
  background-color: #000; 
}

.slide-content {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
}


The background color is working but not the images. I cannot see the images

Check in different browsers and please clear your browser cache one more thing you can do is Copy and paste the image URL path in the Image tag and then see what happens please try these things then let me I will check your issue through Google Meet with any desk to check your issue. Share your repositroy i will check the issue.

https://github.com/Giathi-Daniel/EXTION-INFOTECH/tree/main/03%20-%20Ecommerce%20page/e-commerce%20website

I have figured out your issue you are placing style on the wrong div and the background image is showing

<Slider {...sliderSettings} className="hero-slider">
{slides.map((slide, index) => (

<div style={{
backgroundImage: url(${slide.backgroundImage}),
backgroundSize: "cover",
backgroundPosition: "center",
height: "60vh"
}}>
        <div className="slide-content">
          <h1>{slide.title}</h1>
          <p>{slide.description}</p>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>
  ))}
</Slider>


it is not a best practice to add a class and inline CSS on div.

If you want to apply for a class on div then you would like to convert your inline CSS into an Object then the object name is used as a class in your div.

Thank you. It's working now perfectly fine
